# Remove app from locations on iOS Files app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, icloud

I have added a picker extension to my app.
By adding that extension, my app is listed under Locations of the iOS Files app.

Is there a way to remove the app from appearing there?

Comment: have you set `TRUE` values for either/both `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` or `UIFileSharingEnabled` in your info.plist file, by any chance?

Comment: I don't have those keys. I also tried to add them and set to FALSE but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you add a file provider extension to your project?  If yes, why did you do that if you don't want your app listed in the files app.  If you just want your app to be able to open files you don't need to add a file provider extension.